# Retrofit OAuth signing with okhttp-signpost get OAuthMessageSignerException for special character

Tags: android, oauth, retrofit2, okhttp, signpost

I am using `Retrofit 2` to make http request in Android App. The server I talk to require `OAuth 1.0` Authorization. I use `okhttp-signpost` from here to handle OAuth signing.

Here's my `build.gradle` for library included:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'se.akerfeldt:okhttp-signpost:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:1.2.1.2'
```

In `MyApi` class, I define `dailyChart` as `Retrofit GET request`:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

@GET("chart")
Call<ChartResponse> dailyChart(@Query("symbol") String symbol);
```

Here's how I make `dailyChart() GET request`:

```
import se.akerfeldt.okhttp.signpost.OkHttpOAuthConsumer;
import se.akerfeldt.okhttp.signpost.SigningInterceptor;

// for OAuth signing
OkHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new OkHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(new SigningInterceptor(consumer))
        .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(.....)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();

MyApi myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);

String symbol = '^KKKL';
Call<ChartResponse> call = myApi.dailyChart(symbol);
```

But I get the below error due to the `^` character in `^KKKL` that I passed to retrofit as `@Query` parameter:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET https://......chart?symbol=^KKKL http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: Could not sign request
E/.......: java.io.IOException: Could not sign request
at se.akerfeldt.okhttp.signpost.SigningInterceptor.intercept(SigningInterceptor.java:48)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
.......
Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index ...: https://.....chart?symbol=^KKKL
at oauth.signpost.signature.SignatureBaseString.generate(SignatureBaseString.java:60)
at oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner.sign(HmacSha1MessageSigner.java:51)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer.sign(AbstractOAuthConsumer.java:109)
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer.sign(AbstractOAuthConsumer.java:120)
at se.akerfeldt.okhttp.signpost.SigningInterceptor.intercept(SigningInterceptor.java:46)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185) 
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69) 
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180) 
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91) 
.......
at oauth.signpost.signature.SignatureBaseString.normalizeRequestUrl(SignatureBaseString.java:65)
at oauth.signpost.signature.SignatureBaseString.generate(SignatureBaseString.java:54)
at oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner.sign(HmacSha1MessageSigner.java:51) 
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer.sign(AbstractOAuthConsumer.java:109) 
at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthConsumer.sign(AbstractOAuthConsumer.java:120) 
at se.akerfeldt.okhttp.signpost.SigningInterceptor.intercept(SigningInterceptor.java:46) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:211) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92) 
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67) 
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185) 
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69) 
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180) 
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
```

So I tried to `url-encode` the `symbol`, before pass in to Retrofit:

```
String symbol = '^KKKL';
try {
    query = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(symbol, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    throw new StockHistoryNotFoundException(null, ex);
}

Call<ChartResponse> call = myApi.dailyChart(symbol);
```

Then I got another error as below. I think Retrofit again encode the already encoded `@Query` parameter I passed in.

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found https:.....chart?symbol=%255EKKKL
```

Anyone know any fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem eventually. In `Retrofit 2` [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html), there is this optional element called `encoded`. What it does is:

> **encoded**
>
> Specifies whether the parameter name and value are already URL
>   encoded.

In `MyApi` class, I change the `@Query symbol` to use `encoded=true`:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

@GET("chart")
Call<ChartResponse> dailyChart(
    @Query(value="symbol", encoded=true) String symbol
);
```

In caller code, encode `symbol` before passing in to `dailyChart`:

```
String symbol = '^KKKL';
try {
    query = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(symbol, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    throw new StockHistoryNotFoundException(null, ex);
}

Call<ChartResponse> call = myApi.dailyChart(symbol);
```

Then `okhttp-signpost` no longer complains about special character issue, & Retrofit doesn't double encode the parameter.